# How to manually configure and start PostgreSQL on windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, configuration, installation

I have application that use mysql database, but now i need to port it to postgres... 
In my current installation i have embedded mySQL binaries, and i manually change my.ini file to change default location of mysql server to apppath, install mySQL service and start it...
Is this possible (and how) in PostgreSQL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 35, accepted):

use pgsql bundle zip  so u know actual path that not requires installation

initialize database

```
initdb.exe <datafolderpath>
```

init.db & pg_ctl is under

> pgsql/bin

start database

```
"pg_ctl" -D "<datafolderpath>" -l logfile start
```

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what Nirmal wrote, what I usually do:

- Download the ZIP distribution from http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgbindownload.do
- Unzip the archive
- Run initdb specifying the location of the desired data directory (note this should **not** reside in `c:\Program Files` as that is not writeable for a regular user. You should create this e.g. in %APPDATA%
- After initdb has finished, adjust settings in (the generated) postgresql.conf (e.g. shared memory, listen addres, log settings and such). I do this using search & replace.
- The start the server using `pg_ctl` as mentioned by Nirmal (and described in the manual).
- Make sure you start PostgreSQL using the same (Windows) user that you used when running initdb to avoid problems with file permissions!
- You can use `pg_ctl register ...` to create a Windows service to automatically start Postgres.

Comment: thanks for response... i already have it installed in appdata with install shield, only problem was how to configure and start it...